# Vertical alignment of label of a graphic within an equation

Tags: amsmath, includegraphics

I am inserting an image of an equation within an `equation` environment. The label of the equation/image is aligned to the bottom of the image (red line). How can I align the label to the vertical centre (green line) of the image?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{equ:equation_01}
\includegraphics{equation.png}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use `\adjincludegraphics[valign=m]{equation.png}` command from `adjustbox` package

Comment: as Andrey says, but why use an image for such an equation?

Comment: Thank you both! Somehow, I couldn't get my equation work in LaTeX. Always some `misplacement something` error which I was unable to solve. By now, my project is super comprehensive, and I couldn't get a meaningful MWE. In a new template, the equation worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Stücke really that is the simplest of math expressions, if you are using images for that, I would question if you gain anything from using latex at all. Math typesetting is TeX's strongest feature and you are not using it at all??????

Comment: Got you. Thanks. I see your point. My code `begin{equation}A=T/x_{out}=\left[\begin{matrix}8&5\\4&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\end{equation}` returns an `error` `Misplaced alignment tab character &. ^^IA=T/x_{out}=\left[\begin{matrix}8&` which I was unable to solve, and I do not have a MWE.  I tried for quite a bit and then started inserting images.

Comment: If you have loaded amsmath that runs without error

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}A=T/x_{out}=\left[\begin{matrix}8&5\\4&2\\\end{matrix}\right]\end{equation} 
\end{document}`

Comment: Yes, but not in my *large* LaTeX project of 200 pages and other packages and I cannot come up with a meaningful MWE. I suppose `amsmath` clashes with some other packages? But I don't know which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move image baseline to their vertical center. For example by `valign=m` of `adjustbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{equ:equation_01}
\includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{equation.png} % <---

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**
It is a bit strange to insert math expression(s) as image(s). LaTeX is wonderful and efficient tools for writing (simple or very complex systems of) equations ...